# Freebase API User Rate Limit Exceeded

Tags: freebase

I got the foloowing error and I do not know how to solve it. I read the [page](https://developers.google.com/freebase/usage-limits) but my problem is not the same as the writer problem (space in URL).

```
com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
"error": {
 "errors": [
{
"domain": "usageLimits",
"reason": "userRateLimitExceededUnreg",
"message": "User Rate Limit Exceeded. Please sign up",
"extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
}
],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "User Rate Limit Exceeded. Please sign up"
  }
  }
```

I checked the page [1](https://developers.google.com/freebase/usage-limits); they mentioned "Freebase allows developers a free quota of up to 100,000 (one hundred thousand) read calls per day per person" and I only quota 49886 read calls.Then I got this error and I do not know how to solve the problem.

Comment: whats your calling code look like?

Comment: seems interesting that your quota is almost exactly half of the limit.

Comment: @MiiinimalLogic `String mId = "/m/015401";  GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic"+mId); url.put("key", properties.get("AIzaSyCyCkR59uSSycEC0N5GtiwNft6oTxLexEI"));
       HttpRequest request = requestFactory.buildGetRequest(url);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a server key for using Freebase API. Also, I defined my query in follwoing way:

```
String query="https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic"+mId+"?key=xxx";            
GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl(query);
HttpRequest request = requestFactory.buildGetRequest(url)
HttpResponse httpResponse = request.execute();
JSONObject response = (JSONObject)parser.parse(httpResponse.parseAsString());
```

The mId is mid in Freebase corpus. In addition, I add the flowing catch based on [this page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreErrors)to prevent error since in each second we can only send 10 requests to Freebase server.

```
catch (HttpResponseException e) {
             if (e.getStatusCode()== 403
                    && (e.getContent().contains("userRateLimitExceededUnreg")
                        || e.getContent().contains("uotaExceeded"))) {
                 System.out.println("sleep");
                 Thread.sleep((2^ n) *1000 + randomGenerator.nextInt(1001));

              }
```